# Unwanted session parameter added to RestKit request

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, restkit

I am trying to login to my RoR backend running Devise, by using RestKit 0.20.0. I am trying to achieve a request with the following parameters:

```
Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"email@mail.com"}
```

But what is actually recieved at the server is the following:

```
Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"email@mail.com", "session"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"email@mail.com"}}
```

Where this session parameter comes from, I have no idea. It is not added when I do a GET, only when doing POST. The login goes through, but the response is completely wrong. By using the right list of parameters, the correct response is given. Below is the the code that sends the request. Any ideas on where this session parameter comes from?

```
- (void)loginWithblock:(void (^)(bool))block
{
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_username, @"email", _password, @"password", nil];
NSString *url = [[MBMSettingsHelper sharedSettingsHelper] authenticationURL];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:nil path:url parameters:params
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                        block(YES);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    block(NO);
}];
}
```

In my appdelegate I have the following mappers:

```
// Mappers for authentication
RKObjectMapping *requestMappingForAuthenticate = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMappingForAuthenticate addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"username" : @"email",
 @"password": @"password"
 }];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptorForAuthenticate = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMappingForAuthenticate objectClass:[MBMUserLoginRequest class] rootKeyPath:nil];

RKObjectMapping *responseMappingForAuthenticate = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[responseMappingForAuthenticate addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"success": @"success",
 @"auth_token": @"token",
 @"email": @"username",
 @"id": @"userId"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorForAuthenticate = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMappingForAuthenticate pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptorForAuthenticate];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptorForAuthenticate];
```

EDIT:

The RestKit logs are posted below. It looks like after the login the mapper starts mapping the login response with a completely different model (a boat in this case)?

```
2013-05-24 01:33:59.649 xxx[8153:637f] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:241 Asked to map source object {
"auth_token" = xxx;
email = "xxx";
id = 2;
success = 1;
} with mapping <RKObjectMapping:0x1d5213a0 objectClass=NSMutableDictionary propertyMappings=(
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d51a120 id => boatId>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ec90 year => year>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ecb0 factory => manufacturer>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d528b40 gearnumber => sterndriveNumber>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d528b80 harbour => homeHarbour>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ea80 enginemanufactory => engineManufacturer>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54e9f0 updated_at => updatedAt>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ed00 created_at => createdAt>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ee70 docknumber => dockNumber>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ed30 insurancecompany => insuranceCompany>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54edd0 model => model>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ede0 name => name>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54f0e0 enginemodel => engineModel>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54f170 enginenumber => engineNumber>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ed40 engineyear => engineYear>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1d54ed50 geartype => sterndriveType>"
)>
2013-05-24 01:33:59.652 xxx[8153:637f] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:862 Starting mapping operation...
2013-05-24 01:33:59.653 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:863 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x1e325070> for '__NSDictionaryM' object. Mapping values from object {
"auth_token" = xxx;
email = "xxx";
id = 2;
success = 1;
} to object {
} with object mapping (null)
2013-05-24 01:33:59.655 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:458 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'id' to 'boatId'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.656 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:480 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'id' to 'boatId'. Value: 2
2013-05-24 01:33:59.657 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'year'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.658 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'factory'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.659 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'gearnumber'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.659 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'harbour'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.660 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'enginemanufactory'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.661 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'updated_at'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.662 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'created_at'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.663 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'docknumber'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.664 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'insurancecompany'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.664 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'model'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.665 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'name'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.666 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'enginemodel'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.667 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'enginenumber'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.667 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'engineyear'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.668 xxx[8153:637f] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:525 Did not find mappable attribute value keyPath 'geartype'
2013-05-24 01:33:59.669 xxx[8153:637f] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:926 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2013-05-24 01:33:59.670 xxx[8153:637f] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:414 Finished performing object mapping. Results: {
"<null>" =     {
    boatId = 2;
};
```

EDIT 2:
When I deleted my other RKResponseDescriptors everything worked. So the problem is that somehow the wrong RKResponseDescriptor is chosen when mapping occurs...

Comment: Please post RestKit logs to see what is actually going on.

Comment: RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

Comment: I'm not sure - does the problem persist? Perhaps you need to adjust your params, as you have all set to nil: `pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil`?

Comment: The problem persists. I do not think that I can use pathPattern or keyPath since my JSON response just comes as a simple array. I have tried sending an object instead of the parameters, but no luck. What I want to do is to send parameters and no object, and then create an object from whatever I get as mappingResult. I do get a result, but it is embedded in a nil array: 

`results={ 
    "<null>" = { 
    success = 1; 
    token = hEvLVVqNcufKtktpdbs2; 
    userId = 2; 
    username = "xx"; 
    }; 
}`

Comment: The pathPattern is the URL you receive the response from. do you have defined more response mappers? please try `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/*", RKLogLevelTrace); ` and post the full log on pastebin or somewhere else.